# Complex $\log$ manipulation rules

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts

I saw this working recently,

$$\log(z)=\log((1/z)^{-1})=-\log(1/z)$$

After some manipulation, this leads to $\arg(1/z)+\arg(z)=0$. Then, defining $z=re^{i\theta}$, we get that $\theta-\theta=0$ from the above equation. So all seems well. But then after choosing an appropriate branch cut, this does not work with $-1$.

But why? Is it because $-1$ is near a branch cut (if defined in this way)? What if $\arg$ was defined from $0$ to $2\pi$ - then $-1$ is not near the branch cut, but this still does not work.

**Q:** At what stage in the manipulations did this go wrong? I suppose there is something about complex logarithms that cannot follow the same rules as real logarithms.

Comment: $\arg(z)+\arg(1/z) = 2k \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But where does the manipulation go wrong? I would want to prove what you wrote, but I got $0$

Comment: I do not know how you came up with $0$. Note that $\arg(1) = 2k \pi$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Once you define a branch cut,$$\log(z)=-\log(1-z)\\\log|z|+i\arg z=-\log(1/|z|)-i\arg(1/z)\\i\arg z+i\arg(1/z)=0$$